# DroneKit: dronekit.APIException: Timeout (Pixhawk)

Tags: dronekit-python

I am not understanding why this is not working. The purpose of this project is to pull telemetry data from the Pixhawk to be sent to a server from the RPi 3

I have been following this two guides
http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html
http://python.dronekit.io/guide/connecting_vehicle.html

Connection from the Rpi and Pixhawk works as I am able to run MAVProxy on the Pi and connect with Mission Planner (Windows)

but when I run the following:

```
from dronekit import connect
vehicle = connect('/dev/ttyAMA0', baud=57600)
print "Heading: %s" % vehicle.heading
```

I receive the following 
"dronekit.APIException: Timeout in initializing connection."

I am not understanding why this is the case or if there is a possible interference with the connections.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Uninstall pymavlink 2.0, and install version 1.1.69 instead.

```
pip uninstall pymavlink

pip install pymavlink==1.1.69
```

Comment: When trying uninstall I get an "ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead" This is also the same error I get when following the arduPilot guild installing droneapi